# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rich'" even though I installed with pip

Tags: python

I'm trying to import the rich python module into my code, but I keep getting a 'ModuleNotFoundError' even thought I used `pip install --user rich` after getting the error, but I still get the same error, I was wondering if anyone has encountered a similar problem and knows how to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Your install of pip may not be using the same Python version that you are trying to import Rich with. Try installing Rich with the following:

```
python -m pip install rich
```

Answer (score 2):

If the following won't work

```
python -m pip install rich
```

Then it should be something to do with dependency conflicts.
I'm having a package named `manimce` that was incompatible with the version of `rich` installed.

You can try upgrading the `rich` module with the following:

```
pip install rich --upgrade
```

Then it will prompt you what is conflicting with the package.

Answer (score 1):

This will happen if the names of your script is `rich.py`

The package loader will prioritise this over the pip library.

The solution is to rename your script to something else e.g. `my_rich.py`

Answer (score 0):

I met the similiar problem when I use lighting pytorch which use a class below to detect whether rich is meet requirement:

```
class RequirementCache:
    def _check_requirement(self) -> None:
        if hasattr(self, "available"):
            return
        try:
            # first try the pkg_resources requirement
            pkg_resources.require(self.requirement)
            self.available = True
            self.message = f"Requirement {self.requirement!r} met"
        except Exception as ex:
            self.available = False
            self.message = f"{ex.__class__.__name__}: {ex}. HINT: Try running `pip install -U {self.requirement!r}`"
            requirement_contains_version_specifier = any(c in self.requirement for c in "=<>")
            if not requirement_contains_version_specifier or self.module is not None:
                module = self.requirement if self.module is None else self.module
                # sometimes `pkg_resources.require()` fails but the module is importable
                self.available = module_available(module)
                if self.available:
                    self.message = f"Module {module!r} available"
```

When

```
pkg_resources.require(self.requirement)
```

raise anything, this class will report rich is not installed

even if just some package conflict exists like this:

```
>>> pkg_resources.require('rich')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/mlx/users/wangjiawen.jarvan/miniconda3/envs/SoVitsSvc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 956, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
File "/mlx/users/wangjiawen.jarvan/miniconda3/envs/SoVitsSvc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 815, in resolve
    dist = self._resolve_dist(
File "/mlx/users/wangjiawen.jarvan/miniconda3/envs/SoVitsSvc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 861, in _resolve_dist
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (Pygments 2.11.2 (/mnt/bn/wjw-nas-arnold/mlx/users/wangjiawen.jarvan/miniconda3/envs/SoVitsSvc/lib/python3.8/site-packages), Requirement.parse('pygments<3.0.0,>=2.13.0'), {'rich'})
```

so, solution is just import rich without detect using module like pkg_resources or RequirementCache of lighting pytorch